# How to get around javascript timeout of 0

Tags: javascript

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hB7gY/16/

I have the following code which controls a slideshow with four quadrants. The idea is to rotate through the slideshow and dynamically change the slides based upon a predefined time frame. For instance, many times a slide has a value of 0, which means instantly load the next slide in the series.

The problem is that when using fadeIn() or animate(), they take longer than the timeout of 0. I've tried incrementing my counters when this happens, but that doesn't work.

EDIT: I think I may not have been clear in my question, but the goal is to be able to load the next image instantly, but still maintain the animation effect on the previous image, so essentially it will appear as if both images are animating simultaneously.

```
var slide_array = <?php echo json_encode( $slides ); ?>;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var c =0;
        var slide = 0;
        var counter = 1000;

            for (var i=0;i<slide_array.length;i++){
                jQuery('#slide_'+i).attr('src', slide_array[i]["url"]);
            }

        var intFn = function(){ 
            clearTimeout(interval);
            c++;
                    slide++;

                    if (slide == slide_array.length) { slide = 0; }

                    if (c == 4){ c = 0; }

                        jQuery('#slide_'+c).attr('src',slide_array[slide]['url']).animate({
                             opacity: 0.5
                         }, 100, function() {
                             jQuery('#slide_'+c).attr('src',slide_array[slide]['url']).animate({
                                opacity: 1
                            }, 100);
                         });

                    counter = slide_array[slide]['duration'] * 1000;

           //if (counter < 1000 ) { counter = 400; }
            interval = setTimeout(intFn, counter);
        }

        var interval = setTimeout(intFn, 2500);
        });
```

Comment: Could you put together a jsfiddle to help us further understand your problem?

Comment: I just put together a fiddle and my browser crashed for the first time in probably a  year :/ I'll try to get it back up.

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hB7gY/16/

Comment: Could you try to have the loading of the next slide wait until the first slide animation is complete? In other words, is there a trigger when the animation is complete that can tell the next slide to start loading?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that will accomplish what I want. Essentially I am trying to load 2-3 frames at the same time, but still with animation, to give the appearance of one large panoramic or one large vertical slide appearing, so waiting for the previous slide will not give this effect. For example, I have one large panoramic image, but it is split into two halves. When this occurs, we set the duration (timeout) to zero, to load the next slide instantly. The problem is that the animation on the previous slide hasn't completed, so it goes all wrong, and that's where I'm hung up.

Comment: Oddly, I think I may have found the bug by putting the code up on fiddle :) I'll let you know for sure.

Comment: So, yes. The current fiddle is fixed. Problem solved. Thanks for the help everyone.